# Diplay Calendar Weeks in Dropdown-Box

Tags: php, date, strftime

I wrote a little script and do not really understand why it is not working. I want to display all calendar weeks (normally 52 weeks per year) inside a dropdown box! I did not find a similar script on the internet, that is why I tried it by myself. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

I only see an empty dropdown box! Would be great if someone can help me. It took me a while to write that part of code.

EDIT:

My functions:

```
<?php
function weekDayToTime($week, $year, $dayOfWeek = 1) {
  //dayOfWeek: 0=sunday, 1=monday, ..., 6=saturday
  $dayOfWeekRef = date("w", mktime (0,0,0,1,4,$year));
  if ($dayOfWeekRef == 0) $dayOfWeekRef = 7;
  $resultTime = mktime(0,0,0,1,4,$year) + ((($week - 1) * 7 + ($dayOfWeek - $dayOfWeekRef)) * 86400);
  $resultTime = cleanTime($resultTime);  //Cleaning daylight saving time hours
  return $resultTime;
};

function cleanTime($time) {
  //This function strips all hours, minutes and seconds from time.
  //For example useful of cleaning up DST hours from time
  $cleanTime = mktime(0,0,0,date("m", $time),date("d", $time),date("Y", $time));
  return $cleanTime;
} 

function weeks($year)
                { 
return date("W",mktime(0,0,0,12,28,$year));
} 
?>

<?php


            $year = date("Y");

            echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>"."<select name='w' onChange='this.form.submit()'>";
for($i=1;$i<=weeks($year);$i++)
{


$start = weekDayToTime($i, $year);
$end   = cleanTime(604800 + $start);

    if(weekDayToTime(date("W"), date("Y")) == $start)
    {
        $selected = "selected = 'selected' /";
    }
    else
    {
        $selected = '/';
    }

echo "<option value='".$i."' $selected>KW ".$i.": ".strftime("%d. %B %Y", $start)." bis ".strftime("%d. %B %Y", $end)."</option>";  
}
echo "</select>"."<input type='hidden' name='y' value='".$year."' />"."</form>"; 

?>
```

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    1 <?php
    2 function weekDayToTime($week, $year, $dayOfWeek = 1) {
    3     $dayOfWeekRef = date("w", mktime (0,0,0,1,4,$year));
    4     if ($dayOfWeekRef == 0) $dayOfWeekRef = 7;
    5     $resultTime = mktime(0,0,0,1,4,$year) + ((($week - 1) * 7 + ($dayOfWeek - $dayOfWeekRef)) * 86400);
    6     $resultTime = cleanTime($resultTime);  //Cleaning daylight saving time hours
    7     return $resultTime;
    8 };  
    9   
   10 function cleanTime($time) {
   11     //This function strips all hours, minutes and seconds from time.
   12     //For example useful of cleaning up DST hours from time
   13     $cleanTime = mktime(0,0,0,date("m", $time),date("d", $time),date("Y", $time));
   14     return $cleanTime;
   15 }   
   16 function weeks($year)
   17 {   
   18     return date("W",mktime(0,0,0,12,28,$year));
   19 }   
   20 
   21 $year = date("Y");
   22 echo('year is ' . var_export($year, true));
   23 echo('weeks is ' . var_export(weeks($year), true));
   24 
   25 echo "<form method='GET' action='index.php'>"."<select name='w' onChange='this.form.submit()'>";
   26 for($i=1;$i<=weeks($year);$i++) {
   27 
   28 
   29     $start = weekDayToTime($i, $year);
   30     $end   = cleanTime(604800 + $start);
   31 
   32     if(weekDayToTime(date("W"), date("Y")) == $start) {
   33         $selected = "selected = 'selected'";
   34     } else {
   35         $selected = '';
   36     }
   37 
   38     echo "<option value='".$i."' $selected>KW ".$i.": ".strftime("%d. %B %Y", $start)." bis ".strftime("%d. %B %Y", $end)."</option> \n";
   39 }
   40 echo "</select>"."<input type='hidden' name='y' value='".$year."' />"."</form> \n";
   41 
   42 ?>
```

This is my version of the code that seems to be working fine, the only thing I changed is removing the slashes from $selected so as to not have self-closing option tags. Could that be it?

Comment: I edited my post and included the functions! Hopefully you can help me out even if I do not believe that it has something to do with my functions.

Comment: that´s it! Awesome! Thank you so much! Just one thing: Right now the months are in English, any idea how I can get the months in another language, like in German?

Comment: you need to use setlocale() as shown in example #1 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: I included setlocale(LC_TIME, "C"); at your code on line "20" but language is still in English. What did I wrong?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE")` should get it in German or maybe "deu_deu"? This page is a little confusing but may help http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88148/discussion-between-christoph-c-and-rubes114).